# How can I check if a string contains an array of values?

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have an array of valid e-mail address domains. Given an e-mail address, I want to see if its domain is valid

```
string[] validDomains = { "@test1.com", "@test2.com", "@test3.com" };
string email = "test@test1.com"
```

Is there a way to check if `email` contains any of the values of `validDomains` without using a loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to recommend you the following code:

```
HashSet<string> validDomains = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "test1.com", "test2.com", "test3.com"
    };
const string email = "test@test1.com";

MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress(email);
if (validDomains.Contains(mailAddress.Host))
{
    // Contains!
}
```

[HashSet.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) is an O(1) operation; while array - O(n). So `HashSet<T>.Contains` is extremely fast. Also, `HashSet` does not store the duplicate values and there is no point to store them in your case.

[MailAddress Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) represents the address of an electronic mail sender or recipient. It contains mail address parsing logic (just not to reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be efficient, not only should you avoid using a loop, but you should construct a `HashSet` for your allowed domains, which would allow O(1) lookup:

```
string[] validDomains = { "@test1.com", "@test2.com", "@test3.com" };
HashSet<string> validDomainsHashSet = new HashSet<string>(validDomains);

string email = "test@test1.com";
string domain = email.Substring(email.IndexOf('@'));
bool isValidDomain = validDomainsHashSet.Contains(domain);
```

It would also make sense to exclude the `@` character from your domains, since it would be present in all and thereby redundant:

```
string[] validDomains = { "test1.com", "test2.com", "test3.com" };
HashSet<string> validDomainsHashSet = new HashSet<string>(validDomains);

string email = "test@test1.com";
string domain = email.Substring(email.IndexOf('@') + 1);
bool isValidDomain = validDomainsHashSet.Contains(domain);
```

Comment: And why would you assume that this is what he wants? This is premature optimization.

Comment: Are you serious? Reducing computational lookup from O(n) to O(1) is premature optimization? Do you even know what that term means?

Comment: @Vitaliy He isn't "assuming that this is what he wants", he is giving the OP a better, more efficient way of getting "what he wants" while simultaneously answering the question.

Comment: Better? Why? because it has better asymptotic performance?

Code should be first of all as concise as possible. Than it should be performant (this is slightly oversimplified for brevity).

Comment: @Vitaliy It doesn't seem less concise to put valid domains in a hash set instead of a string array, especially considering that duplicate domains are superfluous. Additionally there are the aforementioned computational gains. That is what makes this better, while still answering the OPs question. I don't agree with your statement about always writing concise code over "performant" code either but I won't get into that here.

Comment: @Vitaliy: I might agree with you on minor optimizations that give a 10% performance gain at the expense of a 90% code bloat. But this isn't one of those cases. Using a `HashSet` vs using an array can make a difference of orders of magnitudes on large lists. Since the OP didn't specify how large `validDomains` may get in practice, one should assume the worst and make the code scalable.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way with LINQ (this also ignores the case):

```
bool validEmail = validDomains
   .Any(d => email.EndsWith(d, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: @DanielA.White: I didn't downvote on this one; the answer is valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = email.IndexOf("@");
var domain = email.Substring(index)
return validDomains.Any(x=>x == domain);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
        string[] validDomains = { "@test1.com", "@test2.com", "@test3.com" };
        string email = "test@test1.com";
        if (validDomains.Contains(email.Substring(email.IndexOf("@"))))
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With a for each loop in this way :

```
    string[] validDomains = { "@test1.com", "@test2.com", "@test3.com" };
    string email = "test@test1.com";
foreach (string x in validDomains)
{
    if (email.Contains(x))
    {
        //  Do Something
    }
}
```

Without a loop in this way(with LINQ) :

```
if(validDomains.Any(s => email.Contains(s))) {
//Do Something 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
validDomains.Any(validDomain => email.EndsWith(validDomain))
```

Refer to the [documentation of IEnumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @Douglas - they didnt specify that.

Comment: @Douglas, now you are just being mean.